# Problem with simple rectangle collison in OpenGL

Tags: kotlin, opengl, collision-detection, transformation

I try to implement collision detection and collision effects. This is my code for collision detection:

```
    fun collisionDetection(objcect : Renderable?, object2 : Renderable?) : Boolean {
    var collisionX : Boolean = objcect?.getPosition()?.x?.plus(quadSizeX)!! >= object2?.getPosition()?.x!! && object2?.getPosition()?.x?.plus(quadSizeX)!! >= objcect?.getPosition()?.x!!
    var collisionY : Boolean = objcect?.getPosition()?.y?.plus(quadSizeY)!! >= object2?.getPosition()?.y!! && object2?.getPosition()?.y?.plus(quadSizeY)!! >= objcect?.getPosition()?.y!!
    var collisionZ : Boolean = objcect?.getPosition()?.z?.plus(quadSizeZ)!! >= object2?.getPosition()?.z!! && object2?.getPosition()?.z?.plus(quadSizeZ)!! >= objcect?.getPosition()?.z!!

    return collisionX && collisionY && collisionZ }
```

This seems to work, when used with overlapping objects set to overlapping values by transformations. This way

```
        wall.translateLocal(Vector3f(0.0f, 1.0f, -8.0f))
```

and

```
        wall2.translateLocal(Vector3f(0.0f, 2.0f, -8.0f))
```

collisionDetection is true.

When moving wall2 on the z-axis with a different starting point and speed, but x and y position are the same, the effect of the collision should be that wall2 stops moving, when z position of both objects is equal. I tried it this way in the main loop (and many other ways...), but it is still not working:

```
fun render(dt: Float, t: Float) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)


        staticShader.use()
        camera.bind(staticShader)

        wall.render(staticShader)
        wall2.render(staticShader)

        if (collisionDetection(wall, wall2) == true) {
            wall2.getPosition()
        }
        else {wall2.translateLocal(Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -t.toFloat()* 0.001f))}

}
```

I have no idea now, what is wrong and how to fix it. It seems like the collisionDetection function doesn't get information about the changing positions on the z-axis of the wall2. Or maybe I need a different approach.

Comment: We need to know how your Renderable class works. Does it represent a rectangular prism with no rotation to it? Do the X, Y, and Z positions always represent the corner closest to the origin (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: I`ve got a Mesh class for the raw model (which is bind to the vbo etc.). When creating a Renderable this Mesh is transformed into the view space (camera space). Camera is moving on negative z-axis as well as the object wall2. Is that information helpful? The movement works, when simulating "non overlapping" with transformation Vectors, The object does not move, when simulating "overlapping". But with this if clause it moves on an on an on...

Comment: What does `quadSizeX` represent if the meshes aren't rectangular prisms? Does the position of the Renderable represent its center point or some corner of the enclosing rectangular prism?

Comment: QuadsizeX is the result of the calculation to find the size of the quad mesh by min and max. Found in a tutorial. I think the Renderable without any transformation is at the origin 0 0 0 with its center.

Comment: I tried       if (wall2.getPosition().z >= wall.getPosition().z) {
               wall2.translateLocal(Vector3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -t.toFloat()* 0.001f)) }
               else {wall2.getPosition().z = wall.getPosition().z}. This stops the movement, but this is not what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works fine now. Forgot to calculate QuadSize for the second object. This results in two objects on the same z.coordinate.Nothing has been wrong with the function for detecting collisions.